Intermittent crash with Lottie animations on Android
I’m experiencing an intermittent crash in my Android app, and it appears to be related to Lottie animations. The crash happens occasionally, and I can’t pinpoint a specific reason why it happens, the only thing I know is that if I enter multiple times on the screen and play the animation sometimes the crash occurs.
The crash log shows the following error:
Optimistic bind failed.
java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: [Optimistic Bind] Didn't bind to resolver in time!
    at com.android.server.pm.InstantAppResolverConnection.waitForBindLocked(InstantAppResolverConnection.java:160)
    at com.android.server.pm.InstantAppResolverConnection.bind(InstantAppResolverConnection.java:225)
    at com.android.server.pm.InstantAppResolverConnection.lambda$optimisticBind$0$InstantAppResolverConnection(InstantAppResolverConnection.java:255)
    at com.android.server.pm.InstantAppResolverConnection$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.run(Unknown Source:2)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:226)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:313)
    at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:67)

In my onDestroy() method, I am explicitly stopping and cleaning up Lottie animations to prevent any potential leaks or lifecycle issues. Here’s the code I’m using:
override fun onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy()

    binding.lottieAnimation.apply {
        cancelAnimation()
        clearAnimation()
        removeAllAnimatorListeners()
        removeAllUpdateListeners()
    }
}

